# Treeviews with Glade (Gtk Gui editor)

Tags: user-interface, gtk, glade, gtktreeview

I'm looking for a way to make a tree **with glade**.

I've already found how to manage lists with all kind of stuff in it, but I can't figure how to properly let an element have childs. I tried by going into the hierarchy tab, and then drag columns and cellrenderers into some others. They move for one second, and then get replaced where they was.

I also tried that kind of drag'n'drop thing on the other "Columns" and "Data" widgets on glade, but it doesn't work either :(.

Does someone have a solution for that? Is it even possible only with Glade? 
I hope i'm clear with my problem.

PS : I'm using Glade 3.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of glade do you use? Did you try to right-click on the treeview and then `edit`?

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, but it seems there's no way of reorganising things hierarchically into a treeview on glade. I succeeded making a flat list (like a table), but nothing that have childs and subchilds...

i'm using glade 3.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the label then you can choose the type of child you want to add.